# How to make a DataFrame from the nested JSON dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

I am trying to make a DataFrame with all values from this address: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/api/pisa/interfacecomponent/3gcb/0/1/energetics. But The DataFrame I get is very messy and it doesnt provide all the information contained in the JSON dictionary. I am using this code but the result is bad:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
url = 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/api/pisa/interfacecomponent/3gcb/0/1/energetics'
JSONContent = requests.get(url).json()
content = json.dumps(JSONContent, indent = 4, sort_keys=True)
data = json.loads(content)
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
print df
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Please be more clear about the target dataframe you want to achieve

Comment: I want to achieve a DataFrame that will contain all the columns that I get when I go to this site: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/pisa/, then click the LaunchPDBePisa button and then click the Interfaces button. I want to parse the green table with the first column NN and the last column CSS. There is an option to download XML but it does not contain all the information as the green table so I wanted to try the API from the url I have posted in the question. Thank you for the interest.